# Acessar dados de SQL Server 2008 pelo MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, linked-server

Alguém sabe se eu posso acessar dados de um banco SQL Server 2008 a partir de um banco MySQL?

Seria algo parecido com Linked Server, mas de forma contrária.

Comment: Como assim? Não ficou muito claro.

Answer (score 2):

Não, você não pode fazer este tipo de acesso, você pode usar o ODBC, MAS terá de instalar o drive certo.

É importante entender que o client deve compreender o protocolo.